# Google Maps GDirections - Route directions between two points on a map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Does this look like it should work? I'm wanting to generate directions from one latitude/longitude to another latitude/longitude.

```
var dirMap = new GMap2($("#dirMap").get(0));
var wp = new Array(2);
wp[0] = new GLatLng(35.742149,139.337218);
wp[1] = new GLatLng(35.735347,139.328485);

var marker = new GMarker(wp[1]);
dirMap.addOverlay(marker);
dirMap.setCenter(wp[0], 12);
dirMap.setUIToDefault();

// load directions
directions = new GDirections(dirMap);
directions.load("from: Waypoint1@21.742149,100.337218 to: Waypoint2@15.740815,100.3267");
```

**The map loads fine**, but *the directions don't come in*. I've tried it this way too:

```
var dirMap = new GMap2($("#dirMap").get(0));
var wp = new Array(2);
wp[0] = new GLatLng(32.742149,119.337218);
wp[1] = new GLatLng(32.735347,119.328485);

var marker = new GMarker(wp[1]);
dirMap.addOverlay(marker);
dirMap.setCenter(wp[0], 12);
dirMap.setUIToDefault();

// load directions
directions = new GDirections(dirMap);
directions.loadFromWaypoints(wp);
```

Same thing... map but no directions. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything obvious at first glance at your code, so my first guess is a failure coming back in for the **GDirections** request (I am also assuming you have checked the javascript error log for any errors, Tools/Error Console if you haven't already done this).

I suggest you add an error handler for your GDirections object, this will give you some indication what is happening with your request:

```
GEvent.addListener(directions, "error", handleErrors);
```

and in the handleErrors callback have a look in:

```
directions.getStatus().code
```

Compare with the [Geo Status Codes](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode.G_GEO_SUCCESS).

EDIT:  Ok, I just tried out [your code](http://www.cannonade.net/geo4.js) here and it [works perfectly](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo4).  I can only assume that there is some other problem on your page that is causing the issue.  Can you post a link in the question so we can check it out ?

Comment: The problem was on my testing box... so no link. After you tested it out, I copied out the code to a fresh html file and successfully got it to load.

At least I know it's not the javascript's fault now. I truly appreciate the help on this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the status (604) I got when I tried in the [Google Maps API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode.G_GEO_UNKNOWN_DIRECTIONS) says:

> The GDirections object could not
>   compute directions between the points
>   mentioned in the query. This is
>   usually because there is no route
>   available between the two points, or
>   because we do not have data for
>   routing in that region.

and this is the code I used (slightly modified):

```
$(function ()
{
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
    {
        var wp = [new GLatLng(35.742149,139.337218), new GLatLng(35.735347,139.328485)];

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
        map.setCenter(wp[0], 12);
        map.setUIToDefault();

        var marker = new GMarker(wp[1]);
        map.addOverlay(marker);

        var directions = new GDirections(map);
        GEvent.addListener(
            directions,
            'error',
            function ()
            {
                console.log(directions.getStatus().code);
            }
        );
        directions.load('from: Waypoint1@21.742149,100.337218 to: Waypoint2@15.740815,100.3267');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code he provided.  I used it verbatim and a correct route was calculated.